# CSS - Anchor tag inside a li tag sizing problems

Tags: css

I'm placing an anchor tag inside a li tag and I wanted the whole li to be clickable. I have that part working.

I also have a currentpage class for highlighting the current page from my menu.
When that class comes into play my lis that are longer in character length go to the next line because the width is too small to hold the characters.

I've played around with the width of the li and the padding of the a I just can't seem to get it to work properly. It was working as I wanted when I had the lis inside the a but I want my HTML to be valid.

My Code:

```css
.sub-menu li {
  width: 185px;
  color: #F0F0F0;
  background-image: url('../images/submenu-li.png');
  display: inline-block; 
 }

.sub-menu li a {
  display:block;
 }
 
 .sub-menu .currentpage a {
  padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
  color: #3385D6;
  background-image: url('../images/currentpage-li.png');
  font-weight: bold;
 }
```

```html
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li <?php if ($thisPage=="lAdmin") echo " class=\"currentpage\""; ?>><a href="index.php?page=lAdmin">Application Licenses</a></li>
 <li class="currentpage"><a href="index.php?page=lAdminDev">Application Devices</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of little tweaks you can make, but here are a couple options off the top of my head that I've used in various scenarios:

The simplest is preventing wrapping and overflowing the text. Anything that overflows gets an ellipsis in this example:

```
.sub-menu .currentpage a {
    /* ...your styles...*/
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Typically my preferred option for navigation is to allow the links to size themselves and adjust for space issues with media queries. This works something like this:

```
.sub-menu li {
    color: #F0F0F0;
    background-image: url('../images/submenu-li.png');
    display: inline-block;  
}

.sub-menu li a {
    display:block;
    /* set padding for all links here */
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    /* set spacing/margin between links here */
    margin: 0 1.5em;
}

.sub-menu .currentpage a {
    color: #3385D6;
    background-image: url('../images/currentpage-li.png');
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media (min-width: 100em) {
    /* Adjust link's spacing and font-sizes to fit better */
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This did help a lot!  Is there a way I could implement where it re sizes, but i have a set minimum size? So that all my smaller ones are the same and just the larger ones re size.

Comment: Yep.. just add `min-width: 185px` or whatever you'd like to the `.sub-menu li a` styles.

Comment: Thank  you! I greatly appreciate it!!

Comment: Np... glad I could help!